# Ionic Vue pass Object via router-link

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I want to pass an object as a prop to another page via a router-link in Ionic-Vue.

Nothing appears to be being passed in when I click on the link that I've created.

This is the link that I'm using.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'movieInfo', params: { movieInfo: movie }}"><h2>{{movie.Name}}</h2></router-link>
```

Index.js

```
      {
        name: 'movieInfo',
        path: 'movieinfo',
        component: () => import('@/views/MovieInfoPage.vue'),
        props: true
      },
```

Props field within the movieInfo page

```
  props:{
    movieInfo:{
      required: true
    }
  },
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or should I handle this differently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare in your `routes` that this route take props and you have to declare your path like this

```
   path: '/movieinfo/:movieInfo',
```

`movieInfo` become a dynamic data and then you can pass it via `router-link`